# Export a Gridview with related table data

Tags: gridview, export, yii2, expand

I'm trying to use the Kartik export widget which works fine, except it's not getting the data in the expand 'function/grid'. Now of course I do understand how it works, and that it's not actually showing anything, just rendering another view. But I have no idea how to do that in the export function.

Here is the gridview code:

```
    <?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'header' => 'Location Name',
            'value' => 'location.name'
        ],
        'quantity',
        [
            'class'=>'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
            'width'=>'50px',
            'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
            },
            'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
            'detailUrl' => Url::to(['/stock/detail-product'])
        ],
    ],
]);
?>
```

Which is:

[image]

**Code for Export:**

```
<?= ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
        [
            'header' => 'Location Name',
            'value' => 'location.name'
        ],
        'quantity',
        [
            'class'=>'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
            'width'=>'50px',
            'value'=>function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
            },
            'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kartik-sheet-style'],
            'detailUrl' => Url::to(['/stock/detail-product'])
        ],
    ], 
        'exportConfig'=> [
        'HTML' => false,
        'TXT' => false
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

Sadly I couldn't find anything on the web for this particular case. Does anyone have any ideas/links for me that I could use?

Anything is fine!

Answer (score 0):

you must set variable ini second modal with has relation in your modal what include gridview in gridcolumns

Answer (score -1):

Try this link it has lot of demo code to try out,
You may get some idea for your issue
http://demos.krajee.com/export-demo